# How do you know in advance the correct syntax?

Tags: c#, syntax

Sorry for such a noob question, but one thing that is annoying me is that until I try something, I do not know the correct syntax, for example:

**To Set a Title**

`Console.Title = "test"`

**To Write a Line**

`Console.WriteLine("test")`

I was just wondering what is the reasoning behind this?

Is there any way I can know/learn in advance what is needed?

Is it simply a matter of trying and if it doesn't work, try the other?

Comment: Learn the language by reading books or tutorials.

Comment: There is no substitute for reading and understanding the manual

Comment: @VVS , @stillstanding , I am reading books, Hence I know that console.Title uses =, and Console.Writeline uses (""), but no book or tutorial I have read says the most basic information such as actually **WHY** to use one or the other, The two answers I have just got has explained perfectly to me what no book I have read has shown.

Comment: @Wil: Here's a starter: Read about what `properties`, `variables` and `methods` are.

Comment: Reading != Understanding

Comment: To anyone..... If you can actually show me a tutorial or book that shows this most basic fact, please say! I can write (basic) programs no problem at the moment, but little things like this are annoying me and I haven't found anywhere that actually explains why instead of just giving a correct example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [Console.Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.title.aspx) is a property, which you set with similar syntax to setting a variable.

```
instance.propertyname = value;
```

Note that this usually ends up executing code in the property, which means a property can calculate stuff before returning it. For that reason, some properties are read-only, for instance a property that returns the number of items in a list or array would not be writeable, you modify that property by adding or removing items in the list instead.

[Console.WriteLine(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb.aspx) is a method, which you call like the second piece of code in your question.

```
instance.methodname(parameters);
```

When I'm unsure, I use intellisense:

```
Console.    <-- i stop typing after the dot/full stop
```

You can wait for the intellisense menu to appear, or use keyboard shortcuts to bring up the intellisense menu, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

In this case, you would have:

[image: Console intellisense]

Here, the two icons mean:

- [image: method] - method
- [image: property] - property

Comment: I feel like such an idiot, I created a new account to ask this question as I felt to stupid to do it on my main one! I know so many "advanced" commands/methods, but all from example - so when I need to do something, I usually modify something I already know. There are so many simple/basic items I trip up on... Feeling so stupid, but this is brilliant to me!

Answer (score 0):

for **properties**, you need `=`, for **method** you need to use `()`

Comment: So Basically, property is anything that already exists and you change, methods are invoked/not known or created before you run?.... Something so simple I am embarrassed to say, but you have made perfect sense.

Comment: A property acts like a variable and you assign values to it. That's why you use the assignment operator `=`. To methods you pass parameters and the parameter list is put into parentheses, even if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, the simple rule is that properties are assigned to with an `=` sign, while methods are invoked with `()`.

Your next question will be 'how do I know when to call a method and when to set a property?'

Once you understand the difference between a method and a property you will have the answer in almost all cases.  I'm not going to explain in detail, but the core distinction is that a property is a value that can be set or retrieved (not always true but good enough for now), while a method is giving an instruction to do something.  So generally if you want to change something, set a property; if you want something to happen, call a method.

If you aren't familiar with other languages and general OO principles - and I'd expect you aren't if you don't know the difference between properties and methods - you need to do some reading.  It's completely possible to teach yourself syntax but you need resources to explain concepts.

Comment: It is fine - I know the difference (believe it or not!), I just never put two and two together as to this being the difference between the = or (), ... Books I have read just go straight to examples for example it had xxxTitle="xxx", xxxwriteline("xxx"), again, now I know...

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer to the direct question: you can't know in advance what to do or what is the proper code same way you don't know what you will be wearing next month.

If it will rain, you will wear something warm. If it will be hot and sunny, you will wear t-shirt.

Same way, if you will need to set title dynamically, you will assign the Title property. If the requirement will be to show bold font, you will use the myElement.Font.Bold property. You can't possibly know in advance what the future holds unless you build time machine.

Bottom line: you can **learn** things in advance so that you will be prepared for the time when you will have to write something, same way that you have in your closet all kinds of clothes for all kinds of weather. But you actually do something only when you *know what you need to do*, when you have a goal.